# npm install failed, could be a network problem?

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

I have a complete Vue project.  I tried to install npm but it failed. The npm version is the newest.  Could it be a network problem?

**Error:**

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gmall-admin@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the gmall-admin@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be enter code herefound in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yaoshuangshuang\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-03T03_40_28_242Z-debug.log
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, It couldn't be a network problem.  
You can try some cleaning methods. First of all try

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then try to delete Node modules folder and then reinstall it:
(first of all, check if you have some components or CSS you edited before delete your node folder)

- `delete node_modules folder`
- `delete package-lock.json file`
- `npm install`

Now you cant try to `npm run dev` / `npm run serve` again